# EJB dependency injection

Tags: dependencies, ejb, netbeans-8, java-ee-7

Please help me to see where I am going wrong. I am trying to use EJB dependency injection to create a new instance of member in my database. I have this following code which was generated by Netbeans (AbstractFacade)

```
package session;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

/**
 *
 * @author JO
 */
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {

    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    public void create(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }

    //removed some code for clarity here, I'm only trying to understand create
}
```

then I have my code for my EJB Member1, I have added a method inside this which takes two STrings as an argument, first name and surname.

```
package entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

/**
 *
 * @author JO
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "member")
@XmlRootElement

public class Member1 implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id_member")
    private Integer idMember;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "number_of_credits")
    private short numberOfCredits;
    // @Pattern(regexp="^\\(?(\\d{3})\\)?[- ]?(\\d{3})[- ]?(\\d{4})$", message="Invalid phone/fax format, should be as xxx-xxx-xxxx")//if the field contains phone or fax number consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;
    // @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message="Invalid email")//if the field contains email address consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "image")
    private byte[] image;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "member1")
    private Collection<AttendedSession> attendedSessionCollection;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "member1")
    private NextSession nextSession;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "memberIdMember")
    private Collection<Block> blockCollection;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "member1")
    private Collection<MemberWithSession> memberWithSessionCollection;

    public Member1() {
    }


    // added this to allow creation of Member in way that suits me
    public Member1(String firstName, String surname){
       this.firstName = firstName;
       this.surname = surname; 

    }

 ///removed other generated code for clarity here
}
```

Then I have this Member1Facade code which again was generated, I have added the code to create and persist a member to the database.

```
  @Stateless
public class Member1Facade extends AbstractFacade<Member1> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "fitnessPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public Member1Facade() {
        super(Member1.class);
    }
     // added this to allow creation of Member in way that suits me
    public Member1 newMember(String firstName, String surname){
        Member1 member = new Member1();
      member.setFirstName(firstName);
       member.setSurname(surname); 
       em.persist(member);
       return member;
    }

}
```

Finally, here is my addMember.java code, which should take the data from a JSP form and the idea is that it will be added via dependency injection to the database.

```
package servlets;

import entity.Member1;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import session.Member1Facade;


public class addMember extends HttpServlet {
@EJB
Member1Facade memberFacade;
  Member1 member;



    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */


    /**
     * declare password as member
     * @param request
     * @param response
     * @throws javax.servlet.ServletException
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {


          try{
            String firstname = request.getParameter("first");
            String surname = request.getParameter("surname");
            String email = request.getParameter("email");
            String phone = request.getParameter("phone");

         memberFacade.newMember(firstname, surname);

      }
      catch (Exception e){
          System.out.println("error");
      }
//some further code removed for brevity

}
```

It all compiles but nothing much happens. I just can't figure what I'm doing wrong and I've spent days looking online.
I'd really appreciate a heads up as to what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You shouldn't create `EJB` object on your own by `new` (line `memberFacade = new Member1Facade()`). `@EJB` annotation is for EJB components injection but you are trying to inject `Member1` object which is normal class - it won't work. You should read more about basics (and inject EJB by interfaces, not classes).

Comment: Thanks for advice so far. I think the problem is that I am reading too much, reading old uni books (I last studied Java EE over a year ago) and looking online. I've now removed the @EJB injection of the Member1 entity class and I understand why. I've moved the code to create a new instance of member (and persist it to the database) to the Member1Facade. It's still compiling but still not working. Any further help would be so appreciated, I'm new at this and trying to learn.

Comment: Well, is processRequest() actually called at any time? It would be a shame if you're spinning your wheels looking at the EJB code (which looks fine although there is no need to generate stuff) when it is simply a small mistake in the web frontend.

Comment: I haven't called processRequest() and to be honest I didn't know much about it!. I think I'm going to have to go back and follow another tutorial from scratch as well as my uni books.